# How to use the Hiverunner shell independently without the JUNIT?

Tags: java, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to use the HiveShell in Hiverunner to do some hive script validation. So far all the examples I found contains the JUNIT integration to create and run the HiveRunner. I just wanted to know, is there anyway to use HiveRunner similar to workerbee?

[HiveRunner Examples](https://github.com/HiveRunner/HiveRunner/tree/main/src/test/java/com/klarna/hiverunner/examples)